# np.loadtxt for a file with many matrixes

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a file that looks something like this:

```
some text
the grids are 
       3 x 3

more text

matrix marker 1 1
3 2 4
7 4 2
9 1 1

new matrix  2 4
9 4 1
1 3 4
4 3 1

new matrix  3 3
7 2 1
1 3 4
2 3 2
```

.. the file continues, with several 3x3 matrices appearing in the same fashion. Each matrix is prefaced by text with a unique ID, though the IDs aren't particularly important to me. I want to create a matrix of these matrixes. Can I use loadtxt to do that?

Here is my best attempt. The `6` in this code could be replaced with an iterating variable starting at 6 and incrementing by the number of rows in the matrix. I thought that `skiprows` would accept a list, but apparently it only accepts integers.

```
np.loadtxt(fl, skiprows = [x for x in range(nlines) if x not in (np.array([1,2,3])+ 6)])

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-7d82fb7ef14a> in <module>()
----> 1 np.loadtxt(fl, skiprows = [x for x in range(nlines) if x not in (np.array([1,2,3])+ 6)])

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.pyc in loadtxt(fname, dtype, comments, delimiter, converters, skiprows, usecols, unpack, ndmin)
    932 
    933         # Skip the first `skiprows` lines
--> 934         for i in range(skiprows):
    935             next(fh)
    936
```

Comment: A single call can't do it.  I suggest reading the file with your own file `readlines`, and passing the simple blocks of numbers (rows with a consistent number of columns) to `loadtxt`, or even parsing them directly.  Those blocks of 9 numbers should be easy to parse.

Comment: @hpaulj how do I pass the block of numbers to `loadtxt`? Your advise is essentially what I try to do in the posted attempt.

Comment: Also, keep in mind this is a simplified problem. My real case has 30x30 matrices.

Comment: Try passing it a list of strings/lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstand, but if you can match the lines preceding the 3x3 matrices, then you can create a generator to feed to `loadtxt`:

```
import numpy as np

def get_matrices(fs):
    while True:
        line = next(fs)
        if not line:
            break
        if 'matrix' in line: # or whatever matches the line before a matrix
            yield next(fs)
            yield next(fs)
            yield next(fs)


with open('matrices.dat') as fs:
    g = get_matrices(fs)
    M = np.loadtxt(g)

M = M.reshape((M.size//9, 3, 3))
print(M)
```

If you feed it:

```
some text
the grids are 
       3 x 3

more text

matrix marker 1 1
3 2 4
7 4 2
9 1 1

new matrix  2 4
9 4 1
1 3 4
4 3 1

new matrix  3 3
7 2 1
1 3 4
2 3 2

new matrix  7 6
1 0 1
2 0 3
0 1 2
```

You get an array of the matrices:

```
[[[ 3.  2.  4.]
  [ 7.  4.  2.]
  [ 9.  1.  1.]]

 [[ 9.  4.  1.]
  [ 1.  3.  4.]
  [ 4.  3.  1.]]

 [[ 7.  2.  1.]
  [ 1.  3.  4.]
  [ 2.  3.  2.]]

 [[ 1.  0.  1.]
  [ 2.  0.  3.]
  [ 0.  1.  2.]]]
```

Alternatively, if you just want to `yield` all lines that look like they might be rows from a 3x3 matrix of integers, match to a regular expression:

```
import re

def get_matrices(fs):
    while True:
        line = next(fs)
        if not line:
            break
        if re.match('\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+', line):
            yield line
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your processing workflow to use steps: first, extract substrings corresponding to your desired matrices, then call `numpy.loadtxt`. To do this, a great way would be:

1. Find matrix start and end with `re`.
2. Load matrix within that range
3. Reset your range and continue.

Your matrix marker seem to be diverse, so you could use a regular expression like this:

```
start = re.compile("\w+\s+matrix\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\n")
end = re.compile("\n\n")
```

Then, you can find start/end pairs and then load the text for each matrix:

```
import io
import numpy as np

# read our data
data = open("/path/to/file.txt").read()

def load_matrix(data, *args):
    # find start and end bounds
    s = start.search(data)
    if not s:
        # no matrix leftover, return None
        return None
    e = end.search(data, s.end())
    e_index = e.end() if e else len(data)

    # load text
    buf = io.StringIO(data[s.end(): e_index])
    matrix = np.loadtxt(buf, *args)    # add other args here

    # reset our buffer
    data = data[e_index:]

    return matrix
```

**Idea**

In this case, my regular expression marker for the start of the matrix has capturing groups `(\d+)` for the matrix dimensions, so you can get the `MxN` representation of the matrix if you wish. List itemI also then search for items with the word "matrix" on the line, with arbitrary leading text and two numbers separated by whitespace at the end.

My match for the end is two "\n\n" groups, or two newlines (if you have Windows line endings, you may need to consider "\r" too).

**Automating This**

Now that we have a way to find a single case, all you need to do is iterate this and populate a list of matrices while you still get matches.

```
matrices = []

# read our data
data = open("/path/to/file.txt").read()

while True:
    result = load_matrix(data, ...)     # pass other arguments to loadtxt
    if not result:
        break
    matrices.append(result)
```